# The type or namespace name 'IDbconnection' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#

I'm have a problem about windows phone as follows "The type or namespace name 'IDbconnection' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)". I'm can't fix error

Comment: I think you might be missing an assembly refreence

Comment: Have you added a reference to the System.Data assembly?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: or maybe windows phone does not support IDbconnection

Comment: Well, _are_ you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I'm deleted line code error and it is fixed

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation already linked by @Gandarez IDBConnection is not supported by Windows Phone. Generally speaking you can always look at the Platforms section of the documentation to see if there is a specific implementation for Windows Phone.

Comment: I'm want to connect database in windows phone use SQL Server database. If you have document about it, can you give me?. Thankyou very much!

Comment: This is a completely different question, which will require a completely different answer. I don't think there is a native client for SQL Server on Windows Phone, as it will make very little sense in terms of scalability. You might want to reconsider your design and include a backend service providing either JSON or XML data gathered from your SQL database that your application could either produce or consume.

Answer (score 0):

C# is case sensitive. `IDbconnection` should be `IDbConnection`, since that is the actual interface in `System.Data`.